# use Jquery in iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iframe and i wont to use jquery to make some edits on the style , how can i do that on iframe ?

```
   <iframe src="domain.com"></iframe>

<script>
$('#div').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: `domain.com` is this your own domain.. or you are loading iframe contents from some other domain

Comment: no its not my own domain

Comment: I think you are running into a sandbox issue. Correct my if I'm wrong, but I heard sth that the browser restricts the use of javascript to other domains through an iframe (like ajax calls to other domains, ok here we have jsonp if the server supports it).

Comment: then the answer is ... You can't do that

Answer (score 0):

According to [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can't. Or if you want to hide whole iframe, you can use simple:

```
$("#iframe_id").hide();
```